# Polymer with Apache server: URL and app-route configuration

Tags: apache, polymer

I made a small Polymer mobile application. I copied the build/bundled folder (deploy files) to a machine with Ubuntu and apache2.

The root is the usual var/www/html. There's an index.html file and then a /src folder with all the other interfaces (htmls) build with Polymer.

Security model for the directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

On Polymer, I configured the app-route on most of the pages, like this:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
```

And some of the pages are like this:

```
<app-route route="{{route}}"
           pattern="/:recordid"
           data="{{routeData}}"></app-route>
```

It's a just basic page routing with Polymer, looking for the name of the page to show. So the navigation with it looks like this:

```
domain.com
domain.com/vehicles
domain.com/vehicles/id_of_the_vehicle
domain.com/customers
```

Besides the first one (index.html), all of the other pages are in the /src folder.

It's all working fine, until I refresh one of the pages. The feature 'pull-down-to-refresh' on Chrome, for instance, automatically refresh the pages. When the refresh happens, the server tries to look for '/vehicles' file, for example, and it will show a 404 error, because there's no such file at the root folder. It's a route used on the app-route component of Polymer to indicate which file to look for...

So I guess I need to treat every request as 'index.html', because this file points to another file (my-app.html) that has all the app-route configurations... the client should handle all of the routes. Is this correct, though? How can I do this? Should I try Express from Node.js as the web server instead of apache?

If I run the app with the local Polymer server (polymer serve --params) for testing purposes, it all works fine, with the refreshes and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as I suspected, I had to treat every request (besides root '/') as index.html

So a simple .htaccess on the root folder solved it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        IndexIgnore */*
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule (.*) index.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but get this error:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using vhosts it can be that you have to prefix your rewrite condition with the document root like this:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # debug with apache since 2.4 mod_rewrite
  # LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  IndexIgnore */*
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # last rule, append query string
  RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L,QSA]
</ifModule>
```